# Etymology of "beaucoup"

Tags: étymologie

It is obvious that "*beaucoup*" is formed from 2 words: *beau* "fine, great" and *coup* "stroke", but what's not so obvious (at least at first glance) is how/why it's evolved to mean "many, much".

I found the following [explanation of *beaucoup*'s etymology on www.etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beaucoup&allowed_in_frame=1):

> French, literally "a great heap," from *beau* "fine, great" (see *beau* (n.)) + *coup* "a stroke," also "a throw," hence, "a heap" (see *coup* (n.)). Cf. Spanish *golpe* "multitude."

I see some logic here but maybe there are more detailed story / other explanations available?

Answer (score 1):

Voici ce que dit le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/beaucoup) :

> ÉTYMOL. ET HIST. − [xiiies. biau cop « grande et belle chose »
>   (Joinville, 221 dans Littré : Nos engins getoient aus leurs; et les
>   leurs aus nostres; mès onques n'oy dire que les nostres feissent biau
>   cop)]; 1. avec valeur de subst. 1379 beaucoup précédé d'un verbe « une
>   grande quantité » (J. de Brie, Bon Berger, éd. Lacroix, 109 dans
>   T.-L., s.v. coup : Et n'est force que les brebis menge[nt] beaucoup au
>   mois de juing); fin xives. beaucoup de + subst. « id. » (Froissart,
>   Chron., II, 320 dans Gdf. Compl. : Qui vous fera encores biaucop de
>   bien); 2. 1465 adv. (J. Aubrion, Journ., ibid. : Le vin en fuit plux
>   chier, et le bledz aussi belcop). Composé de beau* et de coup*.